# I want to integrate my react app with other websites, what are my options

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

I have a React app that communicates with APIs and renders UI (basically), I want to display my React app on other websites, and so far I've seen how to embed React apps using iframes or adding script tags like the approach explained [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-embed-a-react-application-on-any-website-1bee1d15617f)
Does anyone know of any other option please?